# Fetch data from Core Data and display in UITextFields using Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to fetch data from Core Data and display them in UITextFields using Swift. I think I've successfully saved into Core Data using this code:

```
    func insertUserData() {

    let user = UserData(context: managedObjectContext)
    user.full_name = nameTextField.text!
    user.address = addressTextField.text!
    user.phone_number = phoneTextField.text!
    user.email = emailTextField.text!

    do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
        print("Saved Successfully!")
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

where UserData is the entity name in Core Data model and `managedObjectContext` is:

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Now I'm trying to display the saved data in UITextFields in another ViewController using this code:

```
    func loadProfileData() {

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserData", in: managedObjectContext)
    let request: NSFetchRequest<UserData> = UserData.fetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let userInfo = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)
        let userInformation = userInfo as! NSManagedObject // I'm getting crash here: Cast from '[Any]' to unrelated type 'NSManagedObject' always fails
        nameField.text = userInformation.value(forKey: "name") as? String
        addressField.text = userInformation.value(forKey: "address") as? String
        phoneField.text = userInformation.value(forKey: "phone_number") as? String
        emailField.text = userInformation.value(forKey: "email") as? String
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Crash report:

```
    libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
    0x2105a70fc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x148
    0x2105a7100 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x2105a7104 <+8>:  b.lo   0x180a6b11c               ; <+32>
    0x2105a7108 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x2105a710c <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x2105a7110 <+20>: bl     0x180a607d4               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x2105a7114 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x2105a7118 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x2105a711c <+32>: ret
```

Any suggestions please to solve this? Any other better approach?
Thank you for your time and efforts. Answers with code examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
let userInfo = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)
```

or more simply:

```
let userInfo = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
```

since you have already defined `request` as

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<UserData> = UserData.fetchRequest()
```

`userInfo` is always returned as an array of `UserData` as the request could return more than one object (or none). You should test the array contains at least one entry and use `userInfo.first` or whatever best meets your needs. Obviously you can use an `NSPredicate` to filter the returns as you choose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you could just add it as comment not as an answer, because you only suggested code changes, not a solution! NSPredicate is not required and I didn't ask about it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I admit the code change is completely incidental but my answer does contain the solution. You are treating `userInfo` as a single `UserData` instance and it isn't. It's an array of `UserData` and you need to extract your values from within that array. I didn't provide code for that as I assumed you are familiar with working with arrays. I mentioned NSPredicate because your question was unclear whether you fully expect the array to contain only one element or not. If you require a single element then you can filter the results down to one with the appropriate predicate.